# Restarting to play violin

Tags: violin

I'm a seventeen year old Hungarian girl who played violin for 5 years. I went to music school when I was 8 years old and left it at the age 13. This year I started to play again on my own. Currently I'm looking for a violin teacher in France. I finished school so this year I'm trying to figure out that in wich direction should I continue my studies. Even if I thought lately about violin just as a hobby, now it came my mind if might I would have a chance to understand classical music deeper from teacher who know more about it than me at a music academy. Would I have a chance to get in with a few years of practice under a control of a professional? (If I managed to find one..) Or is it too late for me? I just ask because I wouldn't like to make myself to dream about something if it's unpossible. Can I go more far in it than just leave it as a hobby of mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, it would barely even be unusual for someone of your age with your musical history to decide pursue a professional career, though you'd have the same slim to nil chance of becoming a soloist that every other violinist faces and you'd have to put in the same hours of effective practice that other aspiring professional faces. To pursue such a career at your age in the US, I'd suggest that you take lessons now, find a college with a violin teacher you'd like to study with after high school, and work towards that goal for the next 4 years of college. Presumably Hungary's system is different, but you're young enough that your age will not prevent you from reaching musical excellence, though it's possible your local system will throw up barriers that you would not have in the US.

Also in the US, many large cities have extremely good amateur orchestras, where the musicians chose to pursue non-musical careers but still play well enough that they could easily find paying gigs if they chose. Hungary may have a similar groups, or at least a community where you could play with smaller chamber groups.

Comment: I liked this response since it focused primarily on Ms. Czeizing's goals and applicable strategies. At 17 it would be unusual for anyone to be able to identify and to focus on what they would want to become.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is somewhat subjective.  It's never too late and you are young.  If you had wanted to pursue a career as a classical musician then the gap in playing takes you off the standard path.  But whether or not it's too late depends on you.

I was in a similar situation in that I started violin at about 5 and quit at 9 or 10 in favor for guitar.  I tried to pick up the violin again at 15 to join our high school orchestra and it was a disaster for me.  I had literally outgrown the violin.  The orchestra leader put a contra bass in my hands and that worked.  Even though I started late I was able to get up to a division one performance level in a year with private lessons.

If you really want to make violin playing more than a hobby you should start lessons for a while and see what it takes and if you take to it.  If it comes back and you like the work then keep going.  Be objective and listen to the instructor.  It also depends on what type of work you want to get.  You can be a solo player doing small gigs or record your own music without limits.  But if you are dreaming of getting a chair in the Berlin Philharmonic you need to get into the standard education path, private lessons, education at a well known music conservatory, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!:) I will try to do my best